Power Query: Convert existing data set, individual rows into columns based on Dates
I have a data set where a customer may have had multiple assessments over a period of time. Now each customer's behavior towards these assessments may vary, meaning C1 may have had theirs on day 1, day 90, day 200, etc., and then C2 may have had their day 1, day 14, day 21, day 36, and so on.
My goal is to convert these individual rows into columns. Wonder if anyone had a similar requirement before. I am using Excel or Power Query or SQL to process this problem.
CustomerId Date Score 
C1 1/1/2020 9
C1 1/7/2020 14
C1 1/14/2020 26

C2 1/9/2020 34
C2 3/9/2020 30
C2 6/9/2020 24

Output should be in below format:
Customer | Initial Score | Avg_3_months | Avg_6_months  | Avg_9_months | Avg_12_months and so on.

Please [edit] your question to provide more background details on your problem. Telling readers about your research, what you have already tried, and why it didn’t meet your needs will allow them to understand it better.

Provide a sample of input and output . If one customer shows day 14 and day 36, and another customer shows day 90 and day 200, then how do you want to show +3 months and +6 months. Whats the explicit calculation?

use pivot, convert your lines in columns.

could you pls also provide your expected output in markdown table like the sample data?

The below uses SQL Server syntax. (https://dbfiddle.uk/8WMfYXO4)
WITH initial AS (
    SELECT CustomerId, MIN(Date) AS initial_date
    FROM data
    GROUP BY CustomerId
)
SELECT
    a.CustomerId,
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.Date = i.initial_date THEN a.Score END) AS Initial_Score,
    AVG(CASE WHEN a.Date > i.initial_date AND a.Date <= DATEADD(month, 3, i.initial_date) 
        THEN a.Score END) AS Avg_3m,
    AVG(CASE WHEN a.Date > DATEADD(month, 3, i.initial_date) AND a.Date <= DATEADD(month, 6, i.initial_date) 
        THEN a.Score END) AS Avg_6m,
    AVG(CASE WHEN a.Date > DATEADD(month, 6, i.initial_date) AND a.Date <= DATEADD(month, 9, i.initial_date) 
        THEN a.Score END) AS Avg_9m,
    AVG(CASE WHEN a.Date > DATEADD(month, 9, i.initial_date) AND a.Date <= DATEADD(month, 12, i.initial_date) 
        THEN a.Score END) AS Avg_12m
FROM data a
JOIN initial i ON a.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
GROUP BY a.CustomerId
ORDER BY a.CustomerId;

Output:



CustomerId
Initial_Score
Avg_3m
Avg_6m
Avg_9m
Avg_12m




C1
9
20
null
null
null


C2
34
30
24
null
null




Thank you very much, this syntax worked.

How to correctly parse 1/14/2020 dates on all machines
That date is using the format string M/d/yyyy.
Sometimes setting  culture alone can detect how to import. When you're choosing transform column types, include the optional culture.
To Be safe
You should set Format and Culture explicitly.
That ensures parsing dates and numbers is always deterministic.
Date format strings are listed here: powerquery.how/Date.FromText
fun tip: There are combinations where even a safe "iso" format yyyy/MM/dd isn't actually distinct.
= Date.FromText( "1/14/2020", [ Format = "M/d/yyyy" , Culture = "en-us"] )

Stand Alone Example
let 
    ConvertRecord = ( source as text ) as record => [
        segments = Text.Split( sample, " "),
        parsedDate = Date.FromText( segments{1}, [ Format = "M/d/yyyy" , Culture = "en-us"] ),
        return = [ 
            Customer = segments{0},
            Date = parsedDate,
            Score = segments{2}
        ]
    ][return],
    
    sample = "C1 1/14/2020 9", 
    test = ConvertRecord( sample ),

    // just the 
    source = #table( 
        type table [ RawText = text ],
        {   {"C1 1/1/2020 9"}, 
            {"C1 1/7/2020 14"},
            {"C1 1/14/2020 26" }
        } ),

    // 
    convertRecords = Table.TransformColumns( source, {
        {"RawText", ConvertRecord, type record }} ),

    expandRecords = Table.ExpandRecordColumn( convertRecords, "RawText", {"Customer", "Date", "Score"}, {"Customer", "Date", "Score"})
in 
    expandRecords

Next step: Grouping

Use the Group By on the column CustomerId
Add another column and choose "All Rows"

Now you have a nested table partitioned per-user.( That means your calculation doesn't have to filter users )
Or that part might make more sense as a DAX measure. Then you can filter pre-aggregates.
